# Insertar datos de un txt a Mysql mediante un php

Tags: php, mysqli, parsear, txt, base-de-datos

Buenos días a todos, estoy teniendo un pequeño problema con un código que encontre, el cual ejecuta la acción que deseo con el txt, el cual lee estos datos:

ID(PRIMARY AUTO INCREMENT)-NAME_PRODUCTO(VARCHAR DE 155)-PRECIO_PRODUCTO(FLOAT)
(estos valores de acá arriba no estan en el txt, es para que sepan como se llaman y donde se deben de introducir en la bd)

1;zanahoria;100
2;merengue;110
3;melao;120

E inserta en mysql, pero los datos del NAME_PRODUCTO los inserta en la bd como "0"[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este en teoría sería el codigo:

```
<?php

$path = 'facturas.txt';

if(!file_exists($path))
{

    echo "!Archivo no existe!";     

}else{

    //Gestionar aquí conexión a la BD si es de lugar
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
      printf("Error al conectar: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
      exit();
  }else{
      printf("bienvenidos: ");
  }

    $sql="INSERT INTO facturas (id, name_producto, precio_producto) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

    $f = fopen($path, "r");

    //Contador para saltar primera línea. Necesario sólo si el csv incluye las cabeceras
    $linea = 0;

    while ($data = fgetcsv($f, 1000, ';', '"')) 
    { 

        $linea++;

        if($linea == 0)
        continue;

        if(current($data)) 
        { 
            $id = $data[0];
            $name_producto = $data[1];
            $precio_producto = $data[2];
            $stmt->bind_param('sis', $id, $name_producto, $precio_producto);

            //Para fines de depuración
            echo "Insertando: ".$id." - ".$name_producto." - ".$precio_producto."\n";

            $stmt->execute();
        }

    }

    //Cerrar recursos
    fclose($f);

    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Y también me gustaría saber como hago para evitar colocar el id en el txt, debido a que el archivo original del txt no viene con el id.

De antemano, muchas gracias a quien me pueda guiar o ayudar...

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($data);` dentro del `while` y muestra un fragmento de esa salida pulsando en [edit]. Como dice @toto debes poner bien los tipos de dato: `s` significa *string*  y debe usarse para valores de tipo cadena (varchar y otros), `i` significa *integer* y debe usarse para números y `d` significa *double*  y debe usarse para valores decimales. Si el id es auto-incremental no tienes que ponerlo en el  `INSERT`, pues por cada fila el id se creará solo.

Comment: Ah bueno, perfecto, muchas gracias por su guía, me sirvió su aclaración y la del compañero @toto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola creo que el problema lo tienes en la siguiente linea:

```
//donde pasas "sid" tipo de datos es incorrecto. 
 $stmt->bind_param('sis', $id, $name_producto, $precio_producto);
 //ID es entero entonces tiene que ser una "i"
//name_producto es un string deberia ser una "s"
//precio_producto es un double o entero? deberia ser un "d" o "i"
//quedaria así "isd" o "isi"
 $stmt->bind_param('isd', $id, $name_producto, $precio_producto);
```

Comment: Si! Agregué eso y funciono sin ningún problema, ahora si inserta los datos debidos. Gracias!