# Como sacar un resultado de mi bd y comparar con un array?

Tags: php, mysql, array, phpmyadmin, txt

Se que la pregunta es algo confusa, así que voy a tratar de aclarar bien mi duda.

Yo tengo un .txt el cual contiene "codigo;nombreproducto;precio" (123456789;Taza vengador;12000). Esta pregunta ya la había formulado antes y obtuve algunas respuestas que me ayudaron a solucionar mi problema en aquel entonces link: [Cómo insertar datos de un txt.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/378950/insertar-datos-de-un-txt-a-mysql-mediante-un-php)

El dilema es que ahora quiero comparar lo que tengo en este .txt con lo que esta en mi bd. Pero no he encontrado una buena forma de hacer que esto pase, estoy aplicando una manera que se que esta mal(poner un ciclo while dentro de otro) y esto genera que el **id** no sea continuo como les muestro a continuación con el código.

```
<?php

$path = '../productos/productos.txt';
require_once '../configs/db.php';

$db = Database::connect();

if(!file_exists($path))
{

    echo "!Archivo no existe!";     

}else{

    $f = fopen($path, "r");
    $linea = 0;

    while($data = fgetcsv($f, 1000000, ';', '"')){

      $linea++;

      if($linea == 0)
      continue;

      if(current($data)){

        $sql="SELECT * FROM productos";
        $leerDb = $db->query($sql);

        $code = $data[0];
        $nombre = $data[1];
        $precio = $data[2];

        if($leerDb->num_rows){
          NOTE: acá es donde esta el segundo while...
          while($prods = $leerDb->fetch_object()){

          $codedb = $prods->code;

          if($codedb == $code){

            $sql = "UPDATE productos SET nombre='$nombre', precio=$precio WHERE code=$code";
            $save = $db->query($sql);

            if($save){
              echo "Me actualice<br>";
            }else{
              echo "No me actualice<br>";
            }
            
          }else{

            $sql = "INSERT INTO productos VALUES(NULL, $code, '$nombre', $precio)";
            $insert = $db->query($sql);

            if($insert){
              echo "Me cree<br>";
            }else{
              echo "No me cree<br>";
            }

            }
          }
          //NOTE: Si no hay nada en la bd
        }else{
          $sql = "INSERT INTO productos VALUES(NULL, $code, '$nombre', $precio)";
          $insert = $db->query($sql);

          if($insert){
              echo "Me cree<br>";
          }else{
              echo "No me cree<br>";
          }
        }
      }
    }

    //Cerrar recursos
    fclose($f);
    $db->close();
    unlink($path);
}
?>
```

La primera vez que inserta va todo bien, el id va continuo(como pueden ver con los primeros 6 productos) pero al momento de una segunda lectura se salta varios números(el caso del último producto) como pueden ver en esta foto: [image: BdProductos]

Y había encontrado una forma de sacar ese while dentro del otro, aplicando esto:

```
        $sql="SELECT * FROM productos";
    $leerDb = $db->query($sql);

    $datos = array();
    while($prods = $leerDb->fetch_object()){
      $datos[] = $prods;
    }

    $codedb="";
    foreach($datos as $dato){
      $codedb.= $dato->code;
    }

    echo $codedb;

    while($data = fgetcsv($f, 1000000, ';', '"')){
    //CONTINUA EL CODIGO TAL CUAL
```

Pero al momento de comparar los valores **if($codedb == $code)** siempre retorna false. Ya que **$codedb** de esta forma, trae todos los códigos que están en la bd de forma unificada:

```
string(45) "123456789987654321456123123456987654456789120" No me cree
string(45) "123456789987654321456123123456987654456789120" No me cree
string(45) "123456789987654321456123123456987654456789120" No me cree
string(45) "123456789987654321456123123456987654456789120" No me cree
string(45) "123456789987654321456123123456987654456789120" No me cree
string(45) "123456789987654321456123123456987654456789120" No me cree
string(45) "123456789987654321456123123456987654456789120" No me cree
```

Espero haber sido lo más claro posible con mi duda, cualquier cosa edito la pregunta

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende. ¿Cuál es el problema concretamente?

Comment: Hola! Gracias por responder. Te pregunto para aprender ¿Cómo podría formular mejor mi pregunta? Y básicamente, el problema son dos cosas. En la primera parte del código que muestro, tengo dos ciclos while uno dentro de otro, lo cual al inicio no da problemas para el primer insert, pero luego si (Como muestro en la segunda imagen, en el cual pasa del id 6 al id 382) ya que en el .txt me van a pasar productos que existen y no existen, entonces hay es donde hago la comparación de $codedb == $code (para que actualice o inserte dependiendo)

Comment: Y el segundo problema es, como yo quiero sacar ese ciclo while dentro del otro, aplique lo que mostré en el segundo fragmento de código, pero al momento de comparar me trae un string, el cual si te fijas son todos los codigos unificados cosa que no quiero y por eso no compara uno a uno en el $codedb == $code, para que realice el update o insert.

Comment: Stackoverflow funciona por preguntas, por tanto convendría que plantees cada cosa por separado explicando con claridad el contexto. Si he entendido bien estás leyendo un archivo de texto y quieres verificar si los datos que hay en ese archivo existen en la base de datos. Para evitar esos enormes saltos en la columna `id` deberías verificar la NO existencia de los datos antes de insertar, de lo contrario, por cada intento de inserción fallida el contador de la columna `id` aumentará **aunque no haya inserción**, ocurriendo lo que se ve en la imagen, que salta de `6`  a `382`

Comment: Esto es muy simple de hacer, tú puedes por ejemplo crear una función a la que le pases los criterios de verificación, haciendo dentro de esa función un `SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM laTabla WHERE ... criterios`  y devolver la cantidad del COUNT(*). Si es mayor que cero significa que esa fila existe y no la insertas, si es igual a cero, la fila no existe y la insertas.

Comment: No necesitas hacer tanto, en tu script de carga inicial usa [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: @Sal, si no entiendo mal, esta nota: *"The effects are not quite identical: For an InnoDB table where a is an auto-increment column, **the INSERT statement increases the auto-increment value** but the UPDATE does not".* ... Está diciendo que si la tabla es InnoDB la columna auto-incremental aumenta en caso de que el INSERT no ocurra, por lo que `id` seguiría creciendo en los INSERTS que no ocurran.

Comment: @A. Cedano Incrementa con inserción, si hay duplicado, no hay inserción y por lo tanto no hay incremento, pero sí actualización.

Comment: OK, gracias por la aclaración, @Sal.

Comment: Probé los dos métodos que me dijeron y funciono a la perfección. Ahora si inserta sin saltarse varios números del id. Muchísimas gracias a ambos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para dar una respuesta de cómo se realiza este proceso, les comparto el código que me resulto, gracias **@sal y @A. Cedano** quienes me ayudaron a resolver el problema.

```
function compararcodigo($code,$nombre,$precio){
require_once '../configs/db.php';

$db = Database::connect();
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `productos` WHERE code='$code'";
$leerDb = $db->query($sql);
$resultado = $leerDb->fetch_assoc();

if($resultado['COUNT(*)']>0){

$sql = "UPDATE productos SET nombre='$nombre', precio=$precio WHERE code='$code'";
$save = $db->query($sql);

if($save){
  echo "Me actualice<br>";
}else{
  echo "No me actualice<br>";
}

}else{

$sql = "INSERT INTO productos VALUES(NULL, '$code', '$nombre', $precio)";
$insert = $db->query($sql);

if($insert){
   echo "Me cree<br>";
}else{
   echo "No me cree<br>";
  }
 }
}
```

Como ven en la función le paso los datos que obtengo de mi .txt, entonces realiza un **"SELECT COUNT(*)"** en el cual, si su resultado es **>0** realizará un UPDATE, caso contrario se insertará este producto a la tabla "productos".

Y al final el código que lee el .txt queda así:

```
<?php

$path = '../productos/productos.txt';
require_once 'utils.php';

if(!file_exists($path))
{

    echo "!Archivo no existe!";     

}else{

    $f = fopen($path, "r");
    $linea = 0;

    while($data = fgetcsv($f, 1000000, ';', '"')){

      $linea++;

      if($linea == 0)
      continue;

      if(current($data)){

        $code = $data[0];
        $nombre = $data[1];
        $precio = $data[2];

        compararcodigo($code,$nombre,$precio);
      }
    }
    //Cerrar recursos
    fclose($f);
    unlink($path);
 }
?>
```

Espero a alguien más le pueda servir esto como a mi!